# How to create tabs depending on data got from Database

Tags: sharepoint-designer, calendar

I am generating data from SQL Server and displaying it using a calendar. The data is updated according to time and date and changes in every few hours. A few rows of the sample data is below :

```
FXCurrency  DateTimeUpdated     Rate
U.S. dollar 05/12/2023 15:04    83.65
Euro        05/12/2023 15:04    105.48
U.S. dollar 05/12/2023 16:04    84.65
Euro        05/12/2023 16:04    100.48
```

When we click the calendar, the rates for that particular date is populated. How do I create tabs depending on the time that the rates have been updated in the database? i.e. For 12th June, 1 tab for rates updated at 15.04 and another one for rates at 16:04, as shown in the image below :

[image]

My code is as below :

```
<center>
<asp:Calendar runat="server" id="Calendar1" BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Double" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" ForeColor="Black" DayNameFormat="Full">
    <WeekendDayStyle Font-Bold="True" />
</asp:Calendar>
</center>
<br />
<br />
<center>
<asp:GridView runat="server" id="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="Rate_Source" BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Double">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#99CCFF" BorderColor="Black" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:boundfield DataField="FXCurrency" HeaderText="Currency" SortExpression="FXCurrency">
        </asp:boundfield>
        <asp:boundfield DataField="DateTimeUpdated" HeaderText="Date & Time Updated" SortExpression="DateTimeUpdated">
        </asp:boundfield>
        <asp:boundfield DataField="CashBuy" HeaderText="Cash Buy" SortExpression="CashBuy">
        </asp:boundfield>
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#66CCFF" />
</asp:GridView>
</center>
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="Rate_Source" ConnectionString="Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;User ID=;Password=" ProviderName="" SelectCommand="SELECT [FXCurrency],[DateTimeUpdated],ROUND([CashBuy],2) as Cashbuy FROM [FXRate2] WHERE(CONVERT(CHAR(10),[DateTimeUpdated],120)=@newparameter) ORDER BY [DateTimeUpdated] desc">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:controlparameter ControlID="Calendar1" PropertyName="SelectedDate" Name="newparameter" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: How is this related to SharePoint and SharePoint Designer?

Comment: May be, he is talking about the  sp calendar functionality and customizing the cal?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this through sharepoint designer and display it on sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no good answer for this. You cannot do something like this with SharePoint designer, specifically tabs. You will need to write either javascript or (preferably) server side code to handle this.

For instance, one of the approaches I can think of is get data into a SqlReader and create a list of Datatables (List or maybe Dictionary), and based on the tab selected bind these tables to the gridview.

Though I feel you would get much better answers if you post at Programmers.StackExchange.

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the suggestion. I've posted the question on Programmers.StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think choosing a calendar web part is a good choice in your case. IF you are getting data from the SQL better choice would be the Data View web part. You can use calendar control to provide date filter for the data view web part and do  the other transformations there. Have a look at this tutorial http://roxority.com/sharepoint-zen/filtering-sql-data-view-web-parts-in-sharepoint.html